# Can not configuring a Global Date and Time Format

Tags: spring

I wrote a DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory to use for global conversion of LocalDateTime, imitating LocalDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory

```java
package com.taimi.localdatetimedemo.format.date;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.format.AnnotationFormatterFactory;
import org.springframework.format.Formatter;
import org.springframework.format.Parser;
import org.springframework.format.Printer;

/**
 * LocalDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory
 */
public class LocalDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory implements AnnotationFormatterFactory<LocalDateTimeFormat> {

    private static final Set<Class<?>> FIELD_TYPES;

    static {
        Set<Class<?>> fieldTypes = new HashSet<>(1);
        fieldTypes.add(LocalDateTime.class);
        FIELD_TYPES = Collections.unmodifiableSet(fieldTypes);
    }


    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getFieldTypes() {
        return FIELD_TYPES;
    }

    @Override
    public Printer<?> getPrinter(LocalDateTimeFormat annotation, Class<?> fieldType) {
        return getFormatter(annotation, fieldType);
    }

    @Override
    public Parser<?> getParser(LocalDateTimeFormat annotation, Class<?> fieldType) {
        return getFormatter(annotation, fieldType);
    }

    protected Formatter<LocalDateTime> getFormatter(LocalDateTimeFormat annotation, Class<?> fieldType) {
        LocalDateTimeFormater localDateTimeFormater=new LocalDateTimeFormater(annotation.pattern());
        return localDateTimeFormater;
    }
}
```

```java
public @interface LocalDateTimeFormat {

    String pattern() default "";
}
```

```java
package com.taimi.localdatetimedemo.format.date;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.format.Formatter;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

/**
 * LocalDateFormater
 */
public class LocalDateTimeFormater implements Formatter<LocalDateTime> {

    private String pattern;

    public LocalDateTimeFormater(String pattern) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(pattern)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Pattern can't be empty.", null);
        }
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    @Override
    public String print(LocalDateTime localDateTime, Locale locale) {
        return createDateTimeFormatter(locale).format(localDateTime);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(text, createDateTimeFormatter(locale));
    }

    private DateTimeFormatter createDateTimeFormatter(Locale locale) {
        return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern, locale);
    }

}
```

The configuration is

```java
@Configuration
public class TimeConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport  {


    @Override
    public FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService() {
        // DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionService = new DefaultFormattingConversionService(false);
        FormattingConversionService conversionService=new FormattingConversionService();

        conversionService.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(new LocalDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory());

        return conversionService;
    }
}
```

But it always failed in conversion because converterCache can not find a suitable converter or is empty.

The source code of finding converter is showing down below from `GenericConversionService`

```java
    @Nullable
    protected GenericConverter getConverter(TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
        ConverterCacheKey key = new ConverterCacheKey(sourceType, targetType);
        GenericConverter converter = this.converterCache.get(key);
        if (converter != null) {
            return (converter != NO_MATCH ? converter : null);
        }

        converter = this.converters.find(sourceType, targetType);
        if (converter == null) {
            converter = getDefaultConverter(sourceType, targetType);
        }

        if (converter != null) {
            this.converterCache.put(key, converter);
            return converter;
        }

        this.converterCache.put(key, NO_MATCH);
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found out where I was wrong, the @Interface should be

```java
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LocalDateTimeFormat {

    String pattern() default "";
}
```